# How to make GIF animate on "please, wait form"?

Tags: delphi, gif, animated-gif

I would like make a quick non-closable modal dialog, that pops up while do some tasks and goes away when tasks finish.

There are some inherent difficulties:

- Don't block the main UI thread;
- Don't leave system ghosts windows;
- Move tasks to running into a separate thread;
- Allow update the waiting message to the user;
- Handling exceptions from thread to the application;
- Show animated GIF in the dialog;

How to get around these pitfalls?

Below, a practical example of how I would use it:

```
TWaiting.Start('Waiting, loading something...');
try
  Sleep(2000);
  TWaiting.Update('Making something slow...');
  Sleep(2000);
  TWaiting.Update('Making something different...');
  Sleep(2000);
finally
  TWaiting.Finish;
end;
```

Comment: `Sleep(2000)` is the problem. Don't block the main UI thread. You'll need to move the long running tasks into a separate thread.

Comment: Ok, I see, but move my running tasks into a separate thread may be hard way... There are a way to make the TWaiting running into a separate thread?

Comment: No. That way doesn't work. You need to stop blocking the UI thread. That's your problem.

Comment: Perhaps this sounds noob question, but, instead of using VCL, `TWaiting` use `CreateWindow()` (WinAPI) to create the dialog and controls on it. It might work?

Comment: Yes that would work.

Comment: Of course, the VCL windows will not respond while you block the UI and the system will ghost those windows. Stop blocking the UI thread.......

Comment: The intention of `TWaiting` is just give a visual feedback to the user that something is being processed and that it must wait for its completion, then, blocking the UI thread, in this case, is not a condition that worries me...
I have little experience with WinAPI and I'm considering changing the question for a solution to replace my VCL code by a WinAPI code...

Comment: You don't care that your app will be ghosted and become non-responsive?

Comment: If that question is an abstract question, of course I care. Now, if the question is about this specifc event, then the answer is no (since the `TWaiting` window stay on top and be able to give visual feedback, the background windows could be ghosted without harming to the user)

Comment: Or I get it wrong and you're telling me that even using WinAPI, the system will ghost the window TWaiting too?

Comment: Personally I would not be happy to have the system ghost my app and mark it as not responsive

Comment: Ok, so how to do the "task" `Sleep(2000);` running in a separate thread without block the main UI thread? I see `TWaiting.Finish;` execute before the "task" finish..

Comment: Well, you just don't wait in the UI thread. Don't block on the thread. Have the thread send a message when it's done.

Comment: I wrote a code in response. Is that really what you were trying to say I should do? What about the fact that the `TWaiting` does not block the user action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type
  TWaiting = class(TForm)
    WaitAnimation: TImage;
    WaitMessage: TLabel;
    WaitTitle: TLabel;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  strict private
    class var FException: Exception;
  private
    class var WaitForm : TWaiting;
    class procedure OnTerminateTask(Sender: TObject);
    class procedure HandleException;
    class procedure DoHandleException;
  public
    class procedure Start(const ATitle: String; const ATask: TProc);
    class procedure Status(AMessage : String);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TWaiting.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TGIFImage(WaitAnimation.Picture.Graphic).Animate := True;
end;

procedure TWaiting.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

class procedure TWaiting.Start(const ATitle: String; const ATask: TProc);
var
  T : TThread;
begin
  if (not Assigned(WaitForm))then
    WaitForm := TWaiting.Create(nil);

  T := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin
    try
      ATask;
    except
      HandleException;
    end;
  end);

  T.OnTerminate := OnTerminateTask;
  T.Start;

  WaitForm.WaitTitle.Caption := ATitle;
  WaitForm.ShowModal;

  DoHandleException;
end;

class procedure TWaiting.Status(AMessage: String);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
  procedure
  begin
    if (Assigned(WaitForm)) then
    begin
      WaitForm.WaitMessage.Caption := AMessage;
      WaitForm.Update;
    end;
  end);
end;

class procedure TWaiting.OnTerminateTask(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Assigned(WaitForm)) then
  begin
    WaitForm.Close;
    WaitForm := nil;
  end;
end;

class procedure TWaiting.HandleException;
begin
  FException := Exception(AcquireExceptionObject);
end;

class procedure TWaiting.DoHandleException;
begin
  if (Assigned(FException)) then
  begin
    try
      if (FException is Exception) then
        raise FException at ReturnAddress;
    finally
      FException := nil;
      ReleaseExceptionObject;
    end;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Usage:

```
procedure TFSales.FinalizeSale;
begin
  TWaiting.Start('Processing Sale...',
  procedure
  begin
    TWaiting.Status('Sending data to database'); 
    Sleep(2000);
    TWaiting.Status('Updating Inventory');
    Sleep(2000);
  end);
end;
```